# Is shiny side of CD/DVD facing up or down

Tags: dvd, compact-disc

Is shiny side of  CD/DVD facing up or down when inserting into CD/DVD RW for reading out or writing in?

Comment: just remember its not a cup holder :)

Comment: ... nor an automatic cat feeder :) http://engineering.curiouscatblog.net/2006/08/23/automatic-cat-feeder/

Comment: though more seriously, i've seen cds with two shiny sides, only one of which is burn/readable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on how the drive is mounted; the "Burning side/ Image side" must face the optical reader generally down (always at the bottom of the tray so if it is sideways look for that)

The other option to consider is weather the disk is dual sided in which case it depends on which side you want to read/ write to.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by "if it is sideways look for that"? What do the sideways look like?

Answer (score 5):

The shiny side is always facing down.

Comment: Unless it's facing sideways. :-)

Comment: @Xavierjazz: what does it look like when "it's facing sideways"? Pictures will be nice.

Comment: My CD player has a clip that allows me to set it on it's edge rather than on the "bottom". There for it is in a vertical position. The shiny side faces the "bottom" of the tray.